# Calculating number from one collection basing on a nother collection number

Tags: percentages

I have a collection of numbers between 19.75 and 20.25 and a number that is between that borders lets say its 20.10.

Now basing on that need to calculate equivalent of that number (20.10) but in collection between 120 and 160.

I think what I am trying to say what would be equivalent of a number from first collection in a second (number between 120 - 160)

Comment: This is not clear.  What, if anything, is the connection between your "collection of numbers" and the single specified number?

Comment: How do you define the "equivalent number"? Is it so that if you scale the numbers with some constant, the resulting numbers are equivalent?

Comment: I'm just guessing but you could use a transformation that (in the first example) makes $19.075 \rightarrow 0 $ and $20.25 \rightarrow 1$. If the function is linear, then $20.10$ is transformed into
$$
\frac{20.10 - 19.057}{20.25 - 19.075} \approx 0.872
$$
is this somewhere near what you mean? So that just means that $20.10$ is $87.2~\%$ of the way between $19.075$ and $20.25$.

Comment: Aye @MattiP. that is exactly what i mean, Now that i now that percantage, how to get info what that value is in other collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to consider a set with a known minimim and maxmim values. We want to make a transformation that associates a number between $0$ and $1$ to every element in the set, so that the minimim value gets transformed into $0$ and maximum value gets transformed into $1$. All the other values are then somewhere in between. For any set, this transformation is
$$
f(x) = \frac{x - \text{min}}{\text{max} - \text{min}}
$$
It's easy to see that $f(\text{min}) = 0$ and $f(\text{max}) = 1$.

In the example case, we have $\text{min}= 19.75$ and $\text{max}= 20.25$. We want to transform $x=20.10$, resulting in
$$
f(20.10) = \frac{20.10 - 19.75}{20.25 - 19.75} = 0.7
$$
The question was, which value gets transformed into this value ($0.7$) when $\text{min}=120$ and $\text{max}=160$. We just need to form the equation:
$$
\frac{x - 120}{160-120} = 0.7 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x - 120 = 28
$$
and therefore $x=148$. We can check the result:
$$
\frac{148 - 120}{160-120} = 0.7
$$
Therefore, the answer of $x=148$ is correct.