# a function or a factor to scale a list of real numbers from one range to another

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transformation

Edit:

I made a mistake or someone did. The `a and b and max and min` is swapped in the formula I used. Upon switching the `a for min` and `b for max`, the algorithm worked as I expected.

Previously I had

`a = -180`, `b= 180`, and then `min -100`, `max = 100`

instead it should've been

`a = -100`, `b= 100`, and then `min -180`, `max = 180`

And based on the answer below, I figured out that the x is the series I'm working with.

After that it was just matter of pulling the `(x-min)` out of the fraction to make it easier to realize what to do next.

$$f(x)=(x - min)\frac{(b-a)}{max - min} + {a}$$

Since `x` was my series, all I had to do with subtract min (the right number this time), and then the rest was just simple routine.

---

I posted this in a wrong group, but I think this is more of a simple math problem, which I jut can't wrap my mind around.

Let's say you have 2 lists of real numbers.

`list_1` ranges from `-100 to 100` over time.

`list_2` ranges from `-80 to 80` over time. (exact same time as list_1)

And then I have a third list, which is a sum of the list_1 and list_2, (let's call it `list_sum`) thus can range from `-180  to 180`.

I would like to come up with a formula to scale the sum of the lists, `list_sum`, to the `min` and `max` of either `list_1` or `list_2`.

So basically, I'm trying to come up with

```
list_sum * factor
```

or

```
function(list_sum)
```

that should give me the `list_sum`'s `min` and `max` to be within the `range` of `list_1` or `list_2`.

It's gotta be related to (based on some search i've done)

$$f(x) = \frac{(b-a)(x - min)}{max - min} + {a}$$

How so?

If given the `list_sum` (gives me `min` and `max` of my list) and `list_1` (gives me `a` and `b` of the scale) to be scaled to,

`a = -100`, `b= 100`, and then `min -180`, `max = 180`

that gives me

$$\frac{(100-(-100))(x - (-180))}{180- (-180)} + {-100}$$

or

$$\frac{(200)(x + 180)}{360} {-100}$$

Does that seems right to anyone?

if so, how do I use that if my list_sum is to be transformed?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here's, I believe, a similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094759/calculating-number-from-one-collection-basing-on-a-nother-collection-number/3094793#3094793

Comment: yeah that is somewhat similar. but my problem is that the list_sum already exists. i need to now transform the list. which i think is different from plugging one value into the formula.  don't i need an expression for the x up there? but how do I solve for the x up there to operate on the list? are you seeing my problem here? my brain is fried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you have a list (list_sum) and you would like to scale it so that the minimum is some fixed number $a$ and the maximum is another fixed number $b$. In other words, you would like a function $f(x)$ that has the properties
$$
f(\text{min})=a \quad \text{and}\quad f(\text{max})=b
$$
We can make this with a linear function $f(x) = kx+c$. Plugging in the conditions, we get
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{min}\cdot k &+& c &= a \\
 \text{max}\cdot k &+& c &= b\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The values of $k$ and $c$ can be solved for:
$$\tag{1}
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
k = & \frac{b-a}{\text{max}-\text{min}} \\
c = & \frac{a\cdot \text{max}-b\cdot \text{min}}{\text{max}-\text{min}}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Inserting the values and simplifying, we get
$$ \tag{2}
f(x) = \frac{b(x - \text{min}) + a(\text{max}-x)}{\text{max}-\text{min}}
$$
A more computationally efficient way is to first calculate the coefficients from Equation ($1$) and then calculate $f(x) = kx+c$.

Comment: Thank you. This was more involved and I had to go back to the initial formula, but I did find out the source of my problems. I explained in the edited post.