# How to Find the Percentage Between Two Ratios?

Tags: percentages, ratio

If 0% = 900 and 100% = 1800, how do you find the percentage of 1200?

Question: 1200 = ?%

ms = milliseconds

In other words, on a timeline from 0ms to 1800ms, if an object weren't to move until 900ms passed, and it would have moved exactly 0% during that time. What percent would it have moved until it stopped at 1200ms?

This formula would be used on a website :)

Comment: There is not a unique answer to your question as the acceleration has not been specified.

Comment: @AndrewChin This is not needed to solve the problem thank you for your interest :)

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p4gvsyf0l7) tells you why your question is unclear.

Comment: If the scale is linear, then $1200$ would be $\frac{1200-900}{1800-900} = \frac{1}{3} \approx 33.3 \%$.

Comment: Similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3355027/a-function-or-a-factor-to-scale-a-list-of-real-numbers-from-one-range-to-another/3355071#3355071

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A function or a factor to scale a list of real numbers from one range to another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3355027/a-function-or-a-factor-to-scale-a-list-of-real-numbers-from-one-range-to-another). We have over 1 million questions on this site, so it is likely that someone has asked the same question as you. Before asking, please search your question on [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) to see if there are any duplicates.

Comment: @TobyMak That would be the answer, thank you :) In my situation, the lerp cannot be defined. So I apologize for any confusion. And thank you for your resources.

Comment: What is the lerp?

Comment: Linear interpolation. This is what is calculated based on the browser, screen width, and height ratio, and OS. So it's the acceleration or scale I believe you're referring to? Your formula plugged right into my code, thx :)

Comment: @TobyMak Heres your formula in action https://imgur.com/xXYhHkn

Comment: You can self-answer your question on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage can be expressed as a ratio of lengths.

[image]

The longer length which represents $100$ percent is $1800 - 900 = 900$ units long, and the shorter length is $1200 - 900 = 300$ units long. Therefore, $1200$ is $\frac{300}{900} = \frac{1}{3}$ of the way to $1800$, which is around $33.3$ percent.

This is equivalent to linear interpolation as you have mentioned: the gradient of the line between the two endpoints, and the gradient of the point $(x,1200)$ and one endpoint must be equal.